# Directory Getfiles retrieve wrong files path

Tags: asp.net, directoryinfo

I'm trying to access to the path in my application.From frm_VerifyIndentity.aspx.cs to Imgs folder.

[image]

I'm using next below code:

```
string pathRepositories = Request.ApplicationPath + "/IVT/Imgs/";
```

where the value of Request.ApplicationPath is

> /IVT

And I pass this parameter to

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(pathRepositories);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

Where the pathRepositories is concatenation:

> /IVT/IVT/Imgs/

But, the strange, because when I check the value where the directory is looking for, the values is next below

```
C:\IVT\IVT\Imgs\ instead of my pathapplication.
```

Thta's why I get next below error:

[image]

Somebody know why?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx):

> Use this property to construct a URL relative to the application root
>   from a page or Web user control that is not in the root directory.

So `ApplicationPath` gives you relative path, and you're treating it as an absolute path.

With your current approach you could be interested with [`HttpRequest.PhysicalApplicationPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.physicalapplicationpath.aspx), but I'm not sure if this is sound.

Also, consider using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead of concatenating strings yourself.

Comment: What is "not working" and how? You've asked if "somebody know why" and I've explained it to you. What do you expect now? I'm supposed to guess what do you have in mind?